# Python selenium "no such element: Unable to locate element" error

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I tried to find an answer but nothing, only questions solved by frames. Selenium can't find this element by class.

HTML:

```
<html>class="default-theme" lang=""</html>
<body>
    <div data-v-87e3a7ca="" id="app">
        <div data-v-87e3a7ca="" class="app-wrapper">
            <div data-v-87e3a7ca="" class="inventory">
                <div class="inventory-error-modal">
                    <div class="inventory-error-modal__wrapper">
                        <div class="auth-wrapper__close">
                            <img src="/img/close.b276af38.svg" alt="close">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Python code I tried:

```
try:
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(By.CLASS_NAME, "inventory-error-modal"))
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='inventory-error-modal']//div[@class='inventory-error-modal__wrapper']//div[@class='auth-wrapper__close']").click()
except Exception as EXX:
print("EXX")
pass
```

Error:

```
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".inventory-error-modal"}
  (Session info: chrome=110.0.5481.178)
```

Browser search by class result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBAjQ.png

Answer (score 0):

Your first locator looks fine given the HTML you posted. I would guess that either it's in an IFRAME or that particular popup isn't on the page, maybe another popup is. Pages can sometimes have multiple popups depending on the situation.

It looks like you're just trying to close the popup. If that's the case, you can try to click the close IMG that may exist on all the popups.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "img[alt='close']")).click()
```

Comment: Here many button like this, i can try Xpath but it don't work idk why
//div[@class='auth-wrapper__close']//img[@alt='close']

Comment: We can't help you without access to the page without more specific info.

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider a couple of things:

- There is no need to wait for the [*`visibility_of_element_located()`*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50474905/7429447) in one line and invoke click in the next line.
- Generally `<div>` tags aren't clickable, so ideally you should target the decendent `<img>`.
- If your usecase is to click on the element instead of `visibility_of_element_located()` you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

  - Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.inventory-error-modal > div.inventory-error-modal__wrapper > div.auth-wrapper__close > img[alt=close]"))).click()
    ```
  - Using *XPATH*:

    ```
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='inventory-error-modal']/div[@class='inventory-error-modal__wrapper']/div[@class='auth-wrapper__close']/img[@alt='close']"))).click()
    ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions on [NoSuchElementException](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47995294/7429447) in:

- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50315715/7429447)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53442511/7429447)

Answer (score -1):

Your doing your xpath a bit wrong.

You can try

//div[@class='auth-wrapper__close']

Or perhaps this

//div[@class='inventory-error-modal']/div/div/img

Comment: How is his XPath wrong? It finds the element based on the HTML posted.

Comment: I already try this but same problem

Comment: Why dont  you try using action chains to click a specific spot on the screen?

Comment: I did not see the event on img, i think it on parent

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).